# How to change dimension of iframe greater than screen size

Tags: reactjs, iframe, web-inspector

I am trying to make a platform for web developers to see website responsiveness at different breakpoints and for this, I am using iframe to render the website on my website. now I am struggling to add a feature like a google inspect where users can see the responsiveness of the website at different breakpoints even greater than the device screen size.

this is what I am trying but it is not working

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const iframeRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);

    const handleLoadError = () => {
        setIsError(true);
    };

    const handleSizeChange = () => {
        const iframe = iframeRef.current;
        if (iframe) {
            const userScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
            const desiredScreenWidth = 1920; // Adjust as needed

            const scaleFactor = desiredScreenWidth / userScreenWidth;
            iframe.style.transform = `scale(${scaleFactor})`;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleSizeChange);
        handleSizeChange();

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleSizeChange);
        };
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) { }
    }, [isError]);


    return (
        <div className="bg-transparent flex items-center justify-center w-full h-[100vh]">
            <div
                style={{
                    width: '1024px',
                    height: '600px',
                    boxShadow: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 5px 0px 15px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) 4px 0px 6px',
                }}
                className="flex items-center justify-center bg-white rounded-[1rem]"
            >
                <iframe
                    ref={iframeRef}
                    src="https://www.meloverse.in/"
                    title="Your Website at Codify"
                    onError={handleLoadError}
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', transformOrigin: 'top left' }}
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```